# Simple way to concatenate Dataset columns

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset, concatenation

Consider these two datasets:

```
d1 = Transpose@Dataset[<|"a" -> Range[5]|>];
d2 = Transpose@Dataset[<|"b" -> Range[5, 1, -1]|>];
{d1, d2}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What's the simplest way to concatenate them "horizontally" and get the following?

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is there a way without explicitly extracting the contents of the datasets, i.e. resorting to `Normal`?

I would have expected `Join[d1, d2, 2]` to work, but it doesn't.  `Dataset@Join[Normal@d1, Normal@d2, 2]` works but it's complicated.  `Transpose@Join[Transpose[d1], Transpose[d2]]` is also complicated.  For plain old matrices (lists of lists) I'd just use `ArrayFlatten`, which doesn't work on `Dataset`s.

I have the same question for the case where the rows are labelled too:

```
d1 = Dataset[<|"x" -> <|"a" -> 1|>, "y" -> <|"a" -> 2|>, "z" -> <|"a" -> 3|>|>];
d2 = Dataset[<|"x" -> <|"b" -> 4|>, "y" -> <|"b" -> 5|>, "z" -> <|"b" -> 6|>|>];
{d1, d2}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Assume an identical number of rows and identical row labels between `d1` and `d2`.

Comment: +1. I regard the Association[.]  as the more fundamental data structure and I use Dataset[.] as a mere wrapper to limit large outputs.

Comment: By the way I think it could be considered a bug that `Join[d1, d2, 2]` does not work given that `Join` otherwise does.  Have you filed a report?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No, but I will.

Comment: @RomkeBontekoe, `Association`:brick ::`Dataset`:building. The functionality is sophisticated, for example, I wrote 1-line recursive Trie constructor `Query` to index (reconstruct) a variable-depth file system tree.

Answer (score 12):

This looks nicer in a Notebook:

```
Join[d1\[Transpose], d2\[Transpose]]\[Transpose]
```

Unfortunately transposing a Dataset is very slow.  Gordon Coale's alternative is much faster, but the original `Dataset@Join[Normal@d1, Normal@d2, 2]` is more than an order of magnitude faster than that.

Comment: So I didn't overlook anything then, and this is really the shortest way.  I'll just make a function for it.  This problem came up when processing a dataset in two different ways, ending up with two datasets of compatible shapes but different contents (columns).  It is often inconvenient and sometimes very cumbersome to redo the calculations in a way that produces a single dataset in one go.  It's simpler to just continue using what I have and combine them to a single dataset.

Comment: @Szabolcs Damn, I missed `Transpose@Join[Transpose[d1], Transpose[d2]]` in the question and I'm guessing five voters did too.  Should I just delete this?

Comment: I upvoted based on the "looks nicer part" ;)

Comment: @Gordon Okay :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No, keep it.

Comment: I am actually surprised that Join works on Dataset-s, since the documentation states that Join works Association objects (in Details). There is no mention of Dataset-s.

Comment: @Romke Much of the new functionality still in development and largely undocumented.  The best course of action is, in my opinion, to simply try stuff and see what works.

Answer (score 9):

This is fugly but fulfils the need of staying in the `Dataset` domain and is much quicker for large datasets.  Basically if we use the analogy of a dataset being a SQL table - I do what I would do in the same situation.  Create a dummy key on each, join, then drop the dummy key.  Personally for small `Datasets` I prefer the @Mr.Wizard approach from a readability perspective :D

```
d1 = Transpose@Dataset[<|"a" -> Range[50000]|>];
d2 = Transpose@Dataset[<|"b" -> Range[50000, 1, -1]|>];

{
JoinAcross[d1[MapIndexed[Append[#1, "dummy" -> First@#2] &]], 
d2[MapIndexed[Append[#1, "dummy" -> First@#2] &]], "dummy"][All, {"a", "b"}] // AbsoluteTiming, 
(* Transpose approach *)
Join[d1\[Transpose], d2\[Transpose]]\[Transpose] // AbsoluteTiming
}
```

[image: Concatentate cols]

Comment: This demonstrates some interesting functionality but now that I test it Szabolcs's original `Dataset@Join[Normal@d1, Normal@d2, 2]` is more than an order of magnitude faster on your own example.

Answer (score 5):

In version 12 `Join[d1, d2, 2]` seems to work, albeit a bit slower than Szabolcs's `Dataset@Join[Normal@d1, Normal@d2, 2]`.