# Why is Transpose Dataset slow in one direction

Tags: dataset, associations

`Transpose` is faster when it distributes `Keys` at the 2nd level of a Dataset than when it factors them out.

```
 ds[len_] := <|"a" -> Range[len], "b" -> (1/Range[len] // N)|> // Dataset
```

(Using `N` to work around an unrelated bug - will post separately)

```
dst[len_] := ds[len][Transpose]
```

Then,

```
{ds[5], dst[5]}
```

[image]

Normal form:

```
{ds[5] // Normal, dst[5] // Normal} // Column
```

> ```
> <|a->{1,2,3,4,5},b->{1.,0.5,0.333333,0.25,0.2},c->{4,3,2,1,0}|>
> {<|a->1,b->1.,c->4|>,<|a->2,b->0.5,c->3|>,<|a->3,b->0.333333,c->2|>,<|a->4,b->0.25,c->1|>,<|a->5,b->0.2,c->0|>}
> ```

Timing study:

```
{10, 1000, 10000, 50000} // 
  AssociationMap[<|
     "ds time" -> (ds[#] // Transpose // Timing // First), 
     "dst time" -> (dst[#] // Transpose // Timing // 
        First)|> &] // Dataset
```

[image]

Though timing is similar for smaller datasets, it grows to ~40x at 50k rows. By adding more rows this Timing ratio increases further; I've observed 100x in real world time series.

Note `Transpose` in dst constructor using `SetDelayed` contributes a small amount that doesn't affect the conclusion.

What explains this imbalance? If anything I expected that distributing `Keys` would take longer.

Comment: Related: [(83838)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83838/121).  Possibly related, at least in concept: [(25641)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25641/121)

Comment: I'm not quite sure why yet, but replacing your `Transpose` with `Transpose[#, AllowedHeads -> All]&` and the timings are much closer...

Comment: Also, the slowness seems to come from the code you use for the timing, i.e. I can leave your definitions of `ds` and `dst` unchanged but in the timing study I replace the transposes as I mentioned previously, and things are miraculously faster.