# Transpose can't handle fractions

Tags: bugs, dataset, associations

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.2.0**

Note: `Dataset` and `Association` are new in 10.0

---

Related to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84585/why-is-transpose-dataset-slow-in-one-direction) question, why can't `Transpose` handle fractions? (Note the doc pages for `Transpose` hasn't been updated for v10)

Tis is ok using `N`:

```
 <|"a" -> Range[5], "b" -> (1/Range[5] // N)|> // Dataset // Transpose
```

But not as fractions:

```
 <|"a" -> Range[5], "b" -> (1/Range[5])|> // Dataset // Transpose
```

causes `Failure` with `Message` "the first two levels of <|a-> _, b-> _|> cannot be transposed"

Comment: Interestingly *before* the transpose `<|"a" -> Range[5], "b" -> (1/Range[5])|> // Dataset` doesn't format as I would expect; note the `{ }` in the output rather than discrete columns.

Comment: The bug isn't in `Transpose`, but in `Dataset`, which should figure out the right then to do here. Also note that `<|"a" -> Range[5], "b" -> (1/Range[5])|> // Transpose` doesn't work (and for most cases if `op@data` doesn't work then neither does `op@Dataset@data`).

Comment: @StefanR, I know, hence the tags.

Comment: @StefanR, can you answer the other Q related to Transpose? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84585/why-is-transpose-dataset-slow-in-one-direction

Comment: This bug is fixed in Mathematica 10.2.0.

Comment: @StefanR, thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following Algohi's example <s>it seems this is another problem with the underdeveloped TypeSystem functionality behind `Dataset`.</s>  Look at the difference in these input forms:

```
Transpose @ Dataset[<|"a" -> #, "b" -> (1/#)|> & /@ Range[5]]
% // InputForm
```

[image]

> ```
> Dataset[<|"a" -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 
>   "b" -> {1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5}|>, 
>  TypeSystem`Struct[{"a", "b"}, 
>   {TypeSystem`Vector[TypeSystem`Atom[Integer], 5], 
>    TypeSystem`Vector[TypeSystem`Atom[Rational], 
>     5]}], <|"Origin" -> HoldComplete[
>     AssociationTranspose, Dataset`DatasetHandle[
>      261189890384722]]|>]
> ```

Note specifically `` TypeSystem`Vector[TypeSystem`Atom[Rational], 5] ``.

Now the <s>malformed</s> case that does not transpose:

```
Dataset[<|"a" -> Range[5], "b" -> (1/Range[5])|>]
% // InputForm
```

[image]

> ```
> Dataset[<|"a" -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 
>   "b" -> {1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5}|>, 
>  TypeSystem`Struct[{"a", "b"}, 
>   {TypeSystem`Vector[TypeSystem`Atom[Integer], 5], 
>    TypeSystem`Tuple[{TypeSystem`Atom[Integer], 
>      TypeSystem`Atom[Rational], TypeSystem`Atom[
>       Rational], TypeSystem`Atom[Rational], 
>      TypeSystem`Atom[Rational]}]}], 
>  <|"ID" -> 141042475246422|>]
> ```

[Stefan R](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5678/stefan-r) notes that there is a bug in the display of this form, and also in the way `Transpose` is handled by `Dataset`, but the two are unrelated.  Contrary to my earlier assertion the type system behavior is not at fault.  See the comments below for more.

Comment: The second case isn't malformed. It's a perfectly valid type, which you can verify with `TypeSystem\`ValidTypeQ`.

Comment: Also you can use `TypeSystem\`ConformsQ` to verify that `1/Range[5]` does conform to this type.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for the correction.  Would you please explain: (1) why the second case is not formatted as columns; (2) why the transpose fails?

Comment: Those are two distinct bugs. The formatting issue is benign and minor, but the transpose bug is more serious. I have reported these internally.

Comment: @Stefan Thank you, again.  Would you consider answering this question yourself to provide the *correct* perspective?  I would then delete this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it should be like this:

```
Transpose@Dataset@(<|"a" -> (1/#), "b" -> (#)|> & /@ Range[5])
```

Comment: As @Mr.Wizard mentioned as well, `Transpose` is likely not to be the culprit here. Something funny is going on with `Dataset`, or at least with the way that two essentially equivalent `Dataset` objects are displayed. In a way, I think that you are supporting this hypothesis, in that you show with your example that `Transpose` is working just fine, when given the opportunity.

Comment: @MarcoB I expanded on this in my answer below.  This functionality really isn't complete yet based on all the edge cases like this that keep cropping up.